# MySQL select into outfile does not write the file to the directory that I choose

Tags: mysql, select, directory, into-outfile

The following command:

```
select * 
  INTO OUTFILE '\home\user1\NetBeansProjects\project1\dumps\theData.csv'
  FIELDS TERMINATED by ','
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
  from database1
```

Does not write a file called theData.csv to the specified directory.

1. How do I get this file to be written to the specified directory?

Comment: you need to ensure mysql has the write permission to the directory. see this for more details http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select-into.html

Comment: What @ajreal said - check that mysql/mysql has write permission to that folder. Also - this writes to the folder on the mysql server - not to local host.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The path doesn't seem write - if you are on Linux server then I would expect the path with contains slashes and not backslashes, if you are on Windows machine I would expect the driver letter to appears somewhere (and you can't write on a network folder - just local to the DB server machine).

Also, just to eliminate permissions issue or trying to override existing file, try to write to '/tmp/non_existing_file.csv'.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Windows or Linux? You might need to change the back slashes to forward slashes. Also you need to change the settings in MySQL Query browser or Workbench to view this folder as default.